# Why is 'son' in "fit à Swann 'son' thé" in scare quotes?

Tags: choix-de-mot

This is from Proust:

> Odette fit à Swann « son » thé, lui demanda : « Citron ou crème ? »

Odette peppers her French with English and I'm guessing that here 'son thé' is an anglicism but I want to be sure. I looked up the following:

[faire thé](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/fait+th%C3%A9)

And it seems that correct French would be:

Odette fit à Swann un thé

########  UPDATE

I forgot about n-gram viewer.  It appears that in 1880 which is when the narrative takes place although the book was published in 1913, the expression 'his tea' appeared in English 3 times more often than in French though in both languages the expressions were 10 times less frequent than they are now.  See [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28his%20tea%3A%20eng_2019%29%2C%28son%20th%C3%A9%3A%20fre_2019%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)  Still, for me those stats are not convincing enough evidence that 'son thé' was an anglicism in French in 1880.

Comment: It's not an anglicism. "Son thé" means "his tea".

Comment: then why are there scare quotes around 'son'?

Comment: "faire thé" is not correct; https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faire+le+th%C3%A9%2Cfaire+un+th%C3%A9%2Cfaire+th%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3 all false positives or  belonging to speech of the uneducated. (only "faire un thé, faire le thé, faire du thé")

Comment: I know but reverso can find sentences with both those words, they don't have to be back to back.

Answer (score 3):

The quotes are there to stress the possessive.

Proust didn't wrote ***du** thé* (tea) or ***un** thé* (a [cup of] tea) but ***son** tea*, meaning Swann's specific tea.

Here is a quotation from Ko Iwatsu's *Proust entre guillemets*, 2003 (bold mine):

> *Proust utilise beaucoup les guillemets. Cela relève de la lapalissade. Ce sont les guillemets qui, comme chez d'autres écrivains, font apparaître les discours des autres dans « À la recherche du temps perdu ». Ils connaissent essentiellement trois usages : introduire des conversations; **mettre en relief,
> parfois ironiquement, des expressions particulières** des personnages (Françoise, de Charlus, Cottard, etc. ) ou des milieux (mondain, journaliste, militaire, etc.); reproduire des écrits autres que celui du Narrateur. Ces trois usages servent à introduire dans la narration a la première personne des corps étrangers, des mots qui ne sont pas de soi.*

Comment: I'm skeptical that you need scare quotes for that.

Comment: There is no other explanation that would make sense here. When reading this text aloud, I would definitely emphasize ***son***. The scare quotes are there to make it clear that the possessive is "special". There is no anglicism in that phrase, as XouDo already stated.

Comment: Then that will have to be the answer.  Thanks for the umpteenth time.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the possessive with dishes and drinks is quite common in French, and the significations to be attached to this practice are several. They never warrant the use of scare quotes.

- *Talking about a baby*
  Il faut que je lui donne *son* biberon/*sa* bouillie/*sa* soupe/… (*regular meal*)

Here, "son" is used to refer to the meal as something that the child is used to have regularly, and in a routine manner. This usage is not restricted to babies, although, as it  adds connotations to the names of dishes, drinks, and other such pleasant things, the question of the connotations involved becomes complicated. There are  two sorts of them that sooner or later one comes to recognize: the usual ones that do not stem from a particular context and that any locutor can identify, and those that only persons familiar with the extralinguistic context can understand; in this latter case, these connotations can be from endearing to spiteful, not forgetting sarcastic.

- *Talking about a man*
  Après le repas il prend *son* café sur la terrasse. (*regular drinking of coffee after a meal*)
- *In reference to a person inviting people for diner in their home*
  J'aime bien *ses* spaghettis, je n'en ai jamais gouté d'aussi bons. (*the particular way she/he  prepares the dish*)
- *In reference to a person inviting people for diner in their home*
  Elle nous avait prévenu que ce n'était pas *son* vin parce  qu'elle ne pouvait plus s'approvisionner pour l'instant. (*her personal choice of wine, her personal taste in matters of wine*)
- *Talking about a boy*
  Il lui faut *son* café au lait en se levant ou alors il est de mauvaise humeur. (*something that is regularly eaten by the boy  and that he expects*)
- *Talking about a women, for instance*
  Laissez-lui finir *sa* limonade, puis vous pourrez aller laver les vitres ensemble.  (*nothing more than  the glass or can of lemonade that the women is having at the particular time when this is said*)

The use of scare quotes seems to indicate that some one of the usual connotations is being doubted or that there is some  amusing or peculiar quirk about it. It might be found that this is not altogether foreign to Odette's tea "ethos", but I couldn't say much more than this: possibly, these quotes could be meant to hint at a certain endearment perceptible in the way Odette would have used the possessive as applied to Swann and the tea he drank.

> Mais il n’entrait jamais chez elle. Deux fois seulement, dans l’après-
> midi, il était allé participer à cette opération capitale pour elle,
> « prendre le thé ».

> Ce thé en effet avait paru à Swann quelque chose de précieux comme à elle-
> même,

> Aussi, quand elle avait l’air heureux parce qu’elle devait aller à la
> Reine Topaze, ou que son regard devenait sérieux, inquiet et volontaire,
> si elle avait peur de manquer la fête des fleurs ou simplement l’heure
> du thé, avec muffins et toasts, au « Thé de la Rue Royale » où elle
> croyait que l’assiduité était indispensable pour consacrer la réputation
> d’élégance d’une femme, Swann, transporté comme nous le sommes
> par le naturel d’un enfant ou par la vérité d’un portrait qui semble sur
> le point de parler, sentait si bien l’âme de sa maîtresse affleurer à son
> visage qu’il ne pouvait résister à venir l’y toucher avec ses lèvres.